# Django does't send email on the remote server

Tags: django, email

I am trying to send an email when a user fills out a form on my site.
Everything works on my local server, letters are sent.
On a remote timeweb.com server with the same settings, letters are not sent and I am got them.
Tried DEBUG = False and True
I tried different mail services: gmail, mail, yandex, timeweb mail.
In gmail included "Unreliable applications that have access to the account".
And here I included https://accounts.google.com/DisplayUnlockCaptcha
Nothing helps.

Who knows, please tell me where to dig.

'setting.py'

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = "django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend"
EMAIL_HOST_USER = "email@gmail.com"
EMAIL_HOST = "smtp.gmail.com"
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = "Your_Password"
```

Comment: go to your gmail account > security allow less secure app. it will help. google by default block emails sent by unknown devices. https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when ı researched your error  ValueError: EMAIL_USE_TLS/EMAIL_USE_SSL....., ı find another email sending code. I rocemmend you to read this link [SMTP issue in Django web application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52429789/smtp-issue-in-django-web-application). Can you try this:

```
import smtplib

def sendEmail():

    server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
    server.starttls()
    server.login('yourEmailAddress@gmail.com', 'yourEmailPassword')

    try:
        server.sendmail('yourEmailAddress@gmail.com', 'emailAddressBeingSentTo', 'messageBeingSent')
    except:
        print('An error occurred when trying to send an email')

    server.quit()
```

Comment: This method is working. Thank you so much. But I have a problem with encoding. Peaple will write by Russian language. What shoud I do with this problem?

Comment: what is the other problem. Could you give a example? If you want to open new stackoverflow error, I will look. Please send url this place

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66337145/unicodeencodeerror-ascii-codec-cant-encode-character-in-position-0-4-ordina

Answer (score 1):

its a little late but I solved this way: 
I saw a warning when I checked my Google account, its about new login. Its says: "Detected new login!" and gave two choice; It's me - It's not me.
and when I chose 'It's me', my server started the sending email.

Also my settings just like yours

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I am using this email sending situation. This is working my project. I saw this method in https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UH8oHNDfTyQ. If you want to look this url, it work in your project.

```
'setting.py'
EMAIL_BACKEND = "django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend"
EMAIL_HOST_USER = "siberlab01@gmail.com"
EMAIL_HOST = "smtp.gmail.com"
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = "Your_Password"
```

Comment: I have same configuration of email settings. It doesn't work.

Comment: I don' t understand why is not working with this configuration. My configuration is same this email sending situation. Can you look your spam in gmail account? Maybe email came spam area.

Comment: This configurations is okey. But maybe you forget gmail account > security allow less secure app part

Comment: I have chtcked spam, I have tried different email services.

Comment: I switched the security allow less secure app on

Comment: My recommendation finish, I am sorry. If will learn new thing, ı write there

Comment: I too am not able to connect

Answer (score 0):

can you write 'python manage.py shell' in your terminal screen?
After that

1. 'from django.core.mail import send_mail' enter
2. send_mail('django test mail', 'this is django','siberlab01@gmail.com', ['siberlab01@gmail.com'], fail_silently = False )

in 2 section change your gmail account. ıf you try this implementation, can you write which number do you see?
If this number is 0, change fail_silently part with true. If you see 0 number again, this is not working again.

My answer is okey with this same configuration. Look my image.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZJnXo.jpg)

Comment: ValueError: EMAIL_USE_TLS/EMAIL_USE_SSL are mutually exclusive, so only set one of those settings to True.    I have only EMAIL_USE_TLS=True

Comment: I said change the fail_silently = true or false. I dont say 'EMAIL_USE_TLS = True' . send_mail('django test mail', 'this is django','siberlab01@gmail.com', ['siberlab01@gmail.com'], fail_silently = False ) or send_mail('django test mail', 'this is django','siberlab01@gmail.com', ['siberlab01@gmail.com'], fail_silently = True)

Comment: I want to tell about firstly you try with shell command. Becouse when your email sending configuration is correct, your send_mail function maybe is not correct in the project. Therefore, you should try shell command

Comment: I did this - send_mail('django test mail', 'this is django','noreply@raketaweb.eu ', ['noreply@raketaweb.eu '], fail_silently = True )         and I still have ValueError: EMAIL_USE_TLS/EMAIL_USE_SSL are mutually exclusive, so only set one of those settings to True. And

Comment: what happen fail_silently = false like this:  send_mail('django test mail', 'this is django','noreply@raketaweb.eu ', ['noreply@raketaweb.eu '], fail_silently = False)

Comment: I did that in the shell, and I have this error

Comment: if fail_silently = False,    ValueError: EMAIL_USE_TLS/EMAIL_USE_SSL are mutually exclusive, so only set one of those settings to True

Comment: if fail_silently = True, ValueError: EMAIL_USE_TLS/EMAIL_USE_SSL are mutually exclusive, so only set one of those settings to True

Comment: I want to ask that is 'noreply@raketaweb'.eu mail domain and gmail domain same feature?

Comment: I just changed, but this email is working on my local server, if you whould like I can change it to gmail. I did it beacase my hosting doesn't want check it for gmail

Comment: I think change your account. Becouse ı try with gmail account and maybe my modification and configuration only belongs to the gmail account.

Comment: my new answer is the solution to your error