# I have a problem with encoding with russian language for my python script

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to send an email from my python project. But my method doesn't work with russian language.

```
import smtplib

server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
server.starttls()
server.login('mail@gmail.com', 'pasword')
server.sendmail('mail@gmail.com', 'another@gmail.com', 'привет')
server.quit()
```

I have this error:  UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character in position 0-4: ordinal not range(128)
For English it is working.
Python 3.6

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
server.sendmail('email.com', 'email.com', 'привет'.encode('utf-8'))
```